# SQL Server : how to combine CASE WHEN IS NULL with OR statement

Tags: sql-server, null, case

I have a working statement that I need to expand to include another value; that value is `0`. Right now, my statement is as follows:

```
CASE 
   WHEN dbo.tbl.Price IS NULL 
      THEN CAST(dbo.tbl.cost AS NUMERIC(18 , 1)) * 2.2 
   ELSE dbo.tbl.Price 
END
```

I have tried several ways of to re-write this with the `OR` operator without success.

Including the following:

```
CASE 
   WHEN dbo.tbl.Price IS NULL 
      THEN CAST(dbo.tbl.cost AS NUMERIC(18 , 1)) * 2.2 
   OR WHEN 0 
      THEN CAST(dbo.tbl.cost AS NUMERIC(18 , 1)) * 2.2 
   ELSE dbo.tbl.Price 
END
```

Can anyone assist?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a case statement, there is another function that is expressly designed for this, named `isNull(arg1, arg2)`.
this function returns the first argument if it is not null, and the second argument if the first one is null.

```
isNull(dbo.tbl.Price , CAST(dbo.tbl.cost AS NUMERIC(18 , 1)) * 2.2)
```

This actually a special case of a more general fiunction named `coalesce()` which takes 2 to any number of arguments and returns the first one in the list that is not null, so you could also write:

```
coalesce(dbo.tbl.Price , CAST(dbo.tbl.cost AS NUMERIC(18 , 1)) * 2.2)
```

since you also want to return the more complex expression when `dbo.tbl.Price = 0`, you must also use the function `NullIf(arg1, arg2)` which returns null if the first argument is equal to the second argument, and it returns the first argument if they are not equal.

```
isNull(Nullif(dbo.tbl.Price, 0), CAST(dbo.tbl.cost AS NUMERIC(18 , 1)) * 2.2)
```

or

```
coalesce(Nullif(dbo.tbl.Price, 0), CAST(dbo.tbl.cost AS NUMERIC(18 , 1)) * 2.2)
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, this statements works but in all records where the tbl.Price value is NULL ta portion of the statement is being inserted into the table" The snippet below is what is in the table 

CAST(dbo.zItemInventoryAll.Factor AS NUMERIC(18 , 1)) * 2.2

Comment: None of this is clear to me.  Where is the `xItemInventory.Factor` coming from? That syntax or name or whatever is not mentioned anywhere in your question.  Please check (or post) the actual SQL you are using, and the complete result you are seeing as output of the SQL expression.

Comment: I am sorry, I was simplifying my table names and forgot; I copied the cell content to my clipboard, it would read as 

CAST(dbo.tbl.cost AS NUMERIC(18 , 1)) * 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CASE 
  WHEN dbo.tbl.Price IS NULL THEN CAST(dbo.tbl.cost AS NUMERIC(18 , 1)) * 2.2 
  WHEN dbo.tbl.Price = 0 THEN CAST(dbo.tbl.cost AS NUMERIC(18 , 1)) * 2.2 
  ELSE dbo.tbl.Price 
END
```

Comment: Or more simple CASE WHEN tbl.Price IS NULL or tbl.Price = 0 THEN or even more simple CASE WHEN ISNULL(tbl.Price,0) = THEN ..... eliminates having to copy the same formula from one condition to another...

Comment: Thanks Ash, this statement results in an error; specifically: Conversion failed when converting the varvhar value ‘1599.00’ to data type int.

Matt, can you elaborate on your simple statement: CASE WHEN ISNULL(tbl.Price,0) = THEN please?

Comment: @BL - the only reason I can think of error happening is that tbl.Price is not a numeric data type. Try casting else expression to numeric as in "ELSE CAST(tbl.price as Numeric(18,1)"